# My weewx weather station software ftp uploads fail due to time outs

Tags: raspbian

Running weewx on raspbian Jessie. Experiencing lots of FTP upload failures time-outs, which I can see by tailing the syslog.

Answer (score 3):

The issue turned out to be an option in the weewx configuration file enabling "rapidfire" for wunderground. This is a setting that requires the server to send an almost constant stream of data to wunderground. It appears that this level of multi-tasking is beyond the capabilities of the pi, at least as I have it configured. Disabling rapidfire immediately resolved the issue.